# What is the difference between a structured collar and a normal collar in finance?

Tags: options, financial-literacy, option-strategies

How is a structured collar different from an ordinary collar? I failed to find information about the difference online.

Comment: Are you thinking of a [structured product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_product) that might contain options?

Comment: A structured collar looks better with a coat and tie than an unstructured collar does?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a definition:

> A Collar is a protective strategy for a position in the underlying instrument created by purchasing a put and selling a call to partially pay for the put option purchased or vice versa.

Based on that definition, there are [two different types of collars](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/08/protective-collar-bullish-collar.asp). Each is a combination of two simpler strategies:

- Covered Call + Long Put
- Married Put + Short Call

**References**

[Multi-Leg Options Orders](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/multilegorder.asp)